# Google line chart not working

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart

the following code writes data to the screen and this needs to be plotted in a graph. The graph should be similar to the [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOxpH.jpg) So, when the array indicator is calculated (line 112), it contains 3 subarrays: one with a date, one with normalised prices and one with the mRS values. The array indicator is also calculated 3 times: one for AAL, one for ABF and one for ADM. So I need 3 graphs displayed, one for each symbol.
So essentially the multilinechart code needs to be integrated into the transpose code whereby 3 line charts are generated, namely after the calculation of the indicator array

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var prices = [['Date', 'AAL', 'ABF', 'ADM'],
['2016-12-01', 1207.5, 2514.55, 1847.00],
['2016-11-01', 1123.5, 2475.00, 1901.00],
['2016-10-01', 1131, 2462.00, 1917.00],
['2016-09-01', 967.6, 2600.00, 2049.00],
['2016-08-01', 779.8, 3041, 2013.36],
['2016-07-01', 830.5, 2691, 2125.32],
['2016-06-01', 726.9, 2719, 1993.72],
['2016-05-02', 600.1, 2933.644, 1933.282],
['2016-04-01', 763.4, 3053.222, 1792.365],
['2016-03-01', 552.1, 3337.219, 1913.98],
['2016-02-01', 480.25, 3394.019, 1671.716],
['2016-01-04', 277.45, 3138.919, 1712.254],
['2015-12-01', 299.45, 3330.244, 1601.257],
['2015-11-02', 408.65, 3508.387, 1564.58],
['2015-10-01', 546.6, 3418.352, 1556.858],
['2015-09-01', 550.9, 3304.572, 1449.722],
['2015-08-03', 741, 3168.036, 1472.785],
['2015-07-01', 789.923, 3189.803, 1407.223],
['2015-06-01', 894.409, 2840.547, 1317.905],
['2015-05-01', 999.089, 2985.838, 1414.824],
['2015-04-01', 1076.017, 2817.219, 1458.897],
['2015-03-02', 985.457, 2778.762, 1432.678],
['2015-02-02', 1119.873, 3081.488, 1381.177],
['2015-01-01', 1030.099, 3059.794, 1355.894],
['2014-12-01', 1111.081, 3109.098, 1237.909],
['2014-11-03', 1223.068, 3134.425, 1161.125],
['2014-10-01', 1218.441, 2695.038, 1250.082],
['2014-09-01', 1280.913, 2621.644, 1201.39],
['2014-08-01', 1416.038, 2801.704, 1227.186],
['2014-07-01', 1461.646, 2718.524, 1339.334],
['2014-06-02', 1307.163, 2983.722, 1423.904],
['2014-05-01', 1332.301, 2943.89, 1340.253],
['2014-04-01', 1446.106, 2898.044, 1285.099],
['2014-03-03', 1395.374, 2712.71, 1290.464],
['2014-02-03', 1369.37, 2924.382, 1296.79],
['2014-01-01', 1284.4, 2648.331, 1305.827],
['2013-12-02', 1180.646, 2384.961, 1183.829],
['2013-11-01', 1206.584, 2212.07, 1123.282],
['2013-10-01', 1328.227, 2186.987, 1155.815],
['2013-09-02', 1357.743, 1809.787, 1114.245],
['2013-08-01', 1322.413, 1779.881, 1119.517],
['2013-07-01', 1242.815, 1875.387, 1245.585],
['2013-06-03', 1117.474, 1673.764, 1178.112],
['2013-05-01', 1347.412, 1738.319, 1187.878],
['2013-04-01', 1381.396, 1856.318, 1118.274],
['2013-03-01', 1493.496, 1823.7, 1162.796],
['2013-02-01', 1664.242, 1776.693, 1092.085],
['2013-01-01', 1633.503, 1677.881, 1067.642],
['2012-12-03', 1639.998, 1500.404, 1012.645]];

// Pairwise multiplication of the elements in two arrays; for use in mUp and mDown calculation
function dotproduct(a, b) {
  var n = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); i++) n += a[i][1] * b[i];
  return n;
}

// Define array of weights that is global to the program
var weight = [];

// Weighting function
function weights() {
  var k = 1;
  var lambda = 2;
  for (var x = 0.1; x < 20; x++) {
    weight.push([x, k * Math.pow(x/lambda, k-1) * Math.exp(-Math.pow(x/lambda, k)) / lambda]);
  }
}

// Create the weights
weights();
document.write(weight + '<hr>');

// Fetch first row of the prices array and keep the remainder as actual prices
var symbols = prices[0];
prices.shift();

// Loop through all columns of prices
for (var c in prices[0]) {
  var min = prices[0][c];
  var max = prices[0][c];
  var up = [];
  var down = [];
  var indicator = [];

  // Loop through all rows of prices and calculate the minimum and maximum, the up-value and down-value
  for (var r in prices) {
    min = Math.min(prices[r][c], min);             // minimum price, for normalisation
    max = Math.max(prices[r][c], max);             // maximum price, for normalisation
    var last = (typeof prices[parseInt(r)+1] != "undefined") ? prices[parseInt(r)+1][c] : 0;
    up.push(Math.max(prices[r][c] - last, 0));     // up value
    down.push(-Math.min(prices[r][c] - last, 0));  // down value
  }
  document.write('symbol: ' + symbols[c] + '<br>');

  var mUp = [];    // weighted up values
  var mDown = [];  // weighted down values

  // Loop through all values of up and down and apply the weighting to the up and down values progressively
  for (var i in up) {
    mUp.push(dotproduct(weight, up));
    up.shift();    // drop the first element off the up array
    mDown.push(dotproduct(weight, down));
    down.shift();  // drop the first element off the down array
  }
  // Add date and price to indicator array
  for (var r in prices) {
    indicator.push([prices[r][0], (prices[r][c]-min)/max, mUp[r]/(mUp[r]+mDown[r])]);
  }

  // *********
  // Add the code to generate the line graph of array indicator here
  // *********
  document.write('indicator: ' + indicator + '<br>');

  // Calculate percentile
  document.write('first indicator: ' + indicator[0][2] + '<br>');
  // Define a counter
  var count = 0;
  // Count the number of data points smaller than or equal to n
  for (i in indicator) if (indicator[i][2] <= indicator[0][2]) count++;
  document.write('count: ' + count + '<br>');
  // Return the percentile
  document.write('percentile: ' + count/indicator.length + '<br>');
  document.write('<hr>');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the array `prices` is the result of those calculations, you use `.arrayToDataTable()` to interface the data to the Google Visualization API.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Line Chart</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'AAL', 'ABF', 'ADM'],
        ['2016-12-01', 1207.5, 2514.55, 1847.00],
        ['2016-11-01', 1123.5, 2475.00, 1901.00],
        ['2016-10-01', 1131, 2462.00, 1917.00],
        ['2016-09-01', 967.6, 2600.00, 2049.00],
        ['2016-08-01', 779.8, 3041, 2013.36],
        ['2016-07-01', 830.5, 2691, 2125.32],
        ['2016-06-01', 726.9, 2719, 1993.72],
        ['2016-05-02', 600.1, 2933.644, 1933.282],
        ['2016-04-01', 763.4, 3053.222, 1792.365],
        ['2016-03-01', 552.1, 3337.219, 1913.98],
        ['2016-02-01', 480.25, 3394.019, 1671.716],
        ['2016-01-04', 277.45, 3138.919, 1712.254],
        ['2015-12-01', 299.45, 3330.244, 1601.257],
        ['2015-11-02', 408.65, 3508.387, 1564.58],
        ['2015-10-01', 546.6, 3418.352, 1556.858],
        ['2015-09-01', 550.9, 3304.572, 1449.722],
        ['2015-08-03', 741, 3168.036, 1472.785],
        ['2015-07-01', 789.923, 3189.803, 1407.223],
        ['2015-06-01', 894.409, 2840.547, 1317.905],
        ['2015-05-01', 999.089, 2985.838, 1414.824],
        ['2015-04-01', 1076.017, 2817.219, 1458.897],
        ['2015-03-02', 985.457, 2778.762, 1432.678],
        ['2015-02-02', 1119.873, 3081.488, 1381.177],
        ['2015-01-01', 1030.099, 3059.794, 1355.894],
        ['2014-12-01', 1111.081, 3109.098, 1237.909],
        ['2014-11-03', 1223.068, 3134.425, 1161.125],
        ['2014-10-01', 1218.441, 2695.038, 1250.082],
        ['2014-09-01', 1280.913, 2621.644, 1201.39],
        ['2014-08-01', 1416.038, 2801.704, 1227.186],
        ['2014-07-01', 1461.646, 2718.524, 1339.334],
        ['2014-06-02', 1307.163, 2983.722, 1423.904],
        ['2014-05-01', 1332.301, 2943.89, 1340.253],
        ['2014-04-01', 1446.106, 2898.044, 1285.099],
        ['2014-03-03', 1395.374, 2712.71, 1290.464],
        ['2014-02-03', 1369.37, 2924.382, 1296.79],
        ['2014-01-01', 1284.4, 2648.331, 1305.827],
        ['2013-12-02', 1180.646, 2384.961, 1183.829],
        ['2013-11-01', 1206.584, 2212.07, 1123.282],
        ['2013-10-01', 1328.227, 2186.987, 1155.815],
        ['2013-09-02', 1357.743, 1809.787, 1114.245],
        ['2013-08-01', 1322.413, 1779.881, 1119.517],
        ['2013-07-01', 1242.815, 1875.387, 1245.585],
        ['2013-06-03', 1117.474, 1673.764, 1178.112],
        ['2013-05-01', 1347.412, 1738.319, 1187.878],
        ['2013-04-01', 1381.396, 1856.318, 1118.274],
        ['2013-03-01', 1493.496, 1823.7, 1162.796],
        ['2013-02-01', 1664.242, 1776.693, 1092.085],
        ['2013-01-01', 1633.503, 1677.881, 1067.642],
        ['2012-12-03', 1639.998, 1500.404, 1012.645]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Line Chart',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nice, that worked for me,
but I'm wondering the solution gave is working fine but code is very short as compared to mine. what you did exactly ?

Comment: Your array is already a processed result of that complex code of yours, so what you needed was to interface with the Google Visualization API is all that you really needed to do. Go to https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart and look at the first example code. Find the part where there's an array of arrays: `.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
...
        ]);` replace the array inside the parenthesis with your own array of arrays and that's it. Happy coding.:)

Comment: I want three graphs, i.e. one graph for each element. 
how would that be done ?

Comment: Use one column so cut your arrays like so: `['2012-12-03', 1639.998, 1500.404, 1012.645]` to `['2012-12-03', 1639.998]` the next chart would be `['2012-12-03', 1500.404]`, and the 3rd is: `['2012-12-03', 1012.645]`

Comment: didn't get your point, I'll be thankful to you if you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Make a complete  exact copy of my answer. Next, go to the `.arrayToDataTable([` **DATE, 0000.00, 0000.00, 0000.00** `], [...` and on ***each array*** remove the 3rd and 4th element. That should leave you with a chart with a single line. For the next chart, remove 2nd and 4th, and the last chart, remove 2nd and 3rd. If you want these charts on the same page, post a new question.